# CheckBox OnClick Toggled Before OnClick Handler?

Tags: android, checkbox

So I'm working on a list of check boxes. I'm using the OnClickListener to catch the touch event. I've also tried the OnTouch listener and the OnCheckChanged listener. The issue I've come across is the fact that the check box IsChecked value is set to true before it reaches any of these event listeners. So if I were to do something like this:

```
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) 
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
```

It will always hit this if statement and immediately set the checkbox to unchecked because it's setting it as ischecked true before it reaches OnClickListener. The easiest way around this I've found is:

```
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

But this is what I would call hackish. The other option I see being to create a new checkbox class and override the preformClick method.

```
@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();

    final boolean handled = super.performClick();
    if (!handled) {
        // View only makes a sound effect if the onClickListener was
        // called, so we'll need to make one here instead.
        playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }

    return handled;
}
```

But that seems like a lot more work than should need to go in to accomplishing this task.

So, essentially my question is: Is there a method where I can override and intercept the setting of the checkbox before it is actually changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnClickListener` of the CheckBox always gets called after it changed its checked state (as you can see in the `performClick()` method you copied, the `toggle()` method changes the checked state, before calling super's `performClick()`, which will call the `OnClickListener`).

If you don't want to always change the checked state of the CheckBox, then you can override `performClick()` and leave out the `toggle()` method (or only call it if some condition is true).

But if you want to change the state every time a click happens, then the easiest way is to use the `OnClickListener`, and just negate your conditions (e.g. if you want to do something when the checkbox was empty, then you check if the checkbox's new state is not empty).